# Contact form issue using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, contact-form

I added an contact form that uses ajax to my site. I got the code from a Treehouse blog post by Matt West from March, 2014. The code is below.

Overall, the form works well, but I'm having two issues that I can't resolve. The first seems to be minor. It is that after the mail is sent by mailer.php, I'm getting an error message from line "http_response_code(200)" saying that there is an unidentified function. I got around this by just commenting out the http_response_code lines, but I don't know if there is something I need to do to make it function properly.

The other issue is a UX issue. After the mail is sent, and the success message appears, red borders appear around all fields in the form. This doesn't appear to be handled by CSS, so it must be in jquery. I think the red borders are supposed to indicate bad data, but I don't want them to appear when the user had been successful in sending a message. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AJAX Contact Form Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <h1>AJAX Contact Form Demo</h1>
      <div id="form-messages"></div>
        <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="bat/mailer.php">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="field" id="btns">
                <button type="clear">Clear</button>
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 640px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.field {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  color: #999999;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

#btns {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 2.3em;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.8em;
  background: #69c773;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #498b50;
  color: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  width: 27%;
  text-align: center;
}



button+button {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

button:hover, button:focus {
  opacity: 0.75;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.success {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}

.error {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: #b94a48;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border: 1px solid rgba(185, 74, 72, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**jquery-2.1.0.min.js**

**app.js**

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

**mailer.php**

```
<?php
    // My modifications to mailer script from:
    // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            //http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "recipient@email.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            //http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            //http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        //http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The red borders are probably appearing because once the Ajax call completes you are clearing all of the fields.  Since the fields have the `required` attribute set, whatever browser you are using is marking them with a red border to show that they are supposed to have values.  It's not in your CSS or JavaScript at all.

You might try something like this:

```
$("#name, #email, #message").removeAttr("required").val("").attr("required");
```

In place of this:

```
// Clear the form.
$('#name').val('');
$('#email').val('');
$('#message').val('');
```

I only saw it happen in Firefox, and this seemed to stop it from happening.  It removes the `required` attribute before clearing the values, and then adds it back.